# How to deal with the error message of "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement FOREIGN KEY" in yii1.1

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I am encounted an error of "CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement FOREIGN KEY" when I wanted to delete a record on my admin page. I know it is saying the record has a constraint through foreign key. But how to deal with this error message? For example, just warn "you can not delete this record...".

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yxbeauty`.`tbl_project_user_role`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_project_user_role_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_project` (`id`))

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the try{...} and catch{...} to resolve above program, my code is as below.

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    try{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not 
           redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : 
    array('admin'));
    }
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'warning: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

But, I could not echo the warning message. Can you give me your advise?